# V-Brake pads for wet conditions

Tags: brakes, product-rec, brake-pads

In wet conditions, my current brakes are pretty poor. Without switching to disc brakes, what are my options for v-brake pads that work better in the wet?

I'm only thinking about this for my commuting bike, which is mostly a flat ride to and from work. But sometimes the rain can get pretty heavy this time of year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had good luck (with cantilever brakes) with [Velo Orange's Squeal-Free Brake pads](http://www.velo-orange.com/vosqfrbrshan.html), but many people say that the *Salmon* compound brake pads from [Kool Stop](http://www.koolstop.com/brakes/index.php) are the best choice for wet conditions.  The dual-compound Kool Stops are a good idea, since supposedly they work well in all conditions...

My LBS stocks brands, but Kool Stop is a much more usual brand of brake pad to carry.

In general: any brake pads that say they're made for wet conditions.

Comment: I've picked up set of Kool Stop pads, so I can see how well they work next time it's raining. Which will probably be quite soon :)

Comment: Having clean rims and the brakes setup properly is also extremely important.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to switch to a different compound of brake pad. Your LBS should carry winter pads which may work better in the weather conditions you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I personally reccomend using switchable brake pads like these: http://www.torpedo7.com.au/products/UNBVPNN3C

They last pretty long.

It is also useful to clean them after muddy ride or use a file to clean its surface (it should be flat).